# How do I get "xx:creator" value in XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, frontend

I want to get the value from each targeted tag name in xml but seems like the "`getElementsByTagName`" can't find a tag name if contains special character like "`:`". Any work around to for this? I tried "`xx\:creator`" and "`xx%3Acreator`" and they both don't seem to work. A piece of my code below.

```
promise.then(function (response) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xml = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");

    // Get all 'item' tag
    var items = xml.getElementsByTagName("item");

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       title = items[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
       link = items[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].innerHTML;
       pubDate = items[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].innerHTML;
       creator = items[i].getElementsByTagName("xx:creator")[0].innerHTML;

       // Output: undefined
       console.log(items[i].getElementsByTagName("xx:creator")[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getElementsByTagNameNS`, which includes a namespace argument.  You didn't show your XML, so I can't infer the proper namespace to solve your problem exactly.

```
// check the alignment on a number of cells in a table in an XHTML document.
var table = document.getElementById("forecast-table");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var axis = cells[i].getAttribute("axis");
    if (axis == "year") {
        // grab the data
    }
}
```

Here's a namespace example that'd work with the code above.  The namespace definition below maps prefix `h:` to namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

```
<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

</root>
```